# Using group and file references to imitate a real folder in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, filesystems

I have the following directory structure:

```
- container
  - app
    - index.html
    - ...
  - ios
    - mobile.xcodeproj
    - Mobile
    - www # imaginary folder (or could be a real, empty one)
  - android
    - ...
```

`app` contains files shared among an Android and iOS application. I'd like to add a *imaginary* folder to my xcodeproject so that files in `app` look like they really are in `www` inside the `ios` directory (`../app` should look like `./www`).

*I need to exclude certain files in the app directory, thus I can't simply use a symlink and add that folder, because then I can't selective exclude certain files.*

*The reason why I'm going through this trouble is that PhoneGap searches for the file index.html inside the www directory, which don't exist in my case so I need to somehow fake its existence.*

**Anyone know how to solve this?** My guess is to setup folder groups and add file-references, but I can't get it to work properly. Also, let me know if I should elaborate on something.

Comment: You can select several files in XCode->right click->Group - or is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes, the grouping feature is what I'm trying to do but I can't get it to work. It works if I reference a symlinked folder (called www, which point to ../app), but then I can't exclude certain files from the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that when you create a group, you can then specify where the root folder of that group is with Xcode.  In Xcode 4.x, click on the group icon on the left pane.  Open the rightmost pane and click on the top icon that looks like a document.  You'll see "Identity" underneath is "Group Name", "Path", then another entry with no label that has a window-like icon to the right.  Click on that icon to set which folder the group aligns with.

Comment: I've tried that and unfortunately it doesn't work. Could there be some circumstances making this impossible in my case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say it doesn't work.  When you select the folder, then click the window-like icon, does a dialog appear that allows you to select which folder relates to the selected group folder?

Comment: Okay, this could be a flaw with Phonegap, where it can't handle virtual folders / groups and need references. I'll accept the answer since I got no way of testing whether this is a problem with Phonegap or not, and your explanation makes sense even though it didn't work for me.